# Is there a way to clear quests from your journal in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a number of quests in my journal that are already done but got put in a second time due to an unfortunate conversation option. Does anyone know a way to clear these types of quests out of the journal or just drop a quest if necessary?

Answer (score 8):

**No**, there is no in-game way to remove started quests from journal(unless you finish them).

Best way is to use **quest tracking** to organize your journal - e.g. track all wanted quests and keep "duplicates" untracked, it will make a mess of your compass but you can use map as needed.

If you want to add **mods** to your game you can use **[this one](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/26660/?#)** to remove some quests from the journal.Good thing about this one is that you can still complete quests you removed,you just can't see the marker and journal entry.

Via the **console** you can use 
    **`setstage <quest ID> <stage #>`**
Write without the brackets.To find your quest ID and stage # search for your quest on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Quests).

Comment: Waiting also for some kind of mod or save editor to maintain the quest journal. I have a little mess there also.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PC you can use the console command **setstage** followed by the quest ID to "finish" any quest. UESP has the list of quests and inside each you can see its ID.
To open the console command use the tilde-key (~), it sits before the "1" key and under the ESC-key.

If posible, just try to finish the quest by yourself :) unless its bugged of course.

Comment: Using console **will not** disable Steam achievements in Skyrim. Please stop spreading that rumor. (Yes, I use console constantly. No, I have not lost a single achievement due to it. Yes, I even accidentally gained one of them (the "unlock all three words of a shout" one) purely by cheating with the console - I unlocked the words with souls gained by `player.modav dragonsouls 100`.)