# How do I remove Journal entries in Skyrim, or mark them as finished?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to clear quests from your journal in skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/is-there-a-way-to-clear-quests-from-your-journal-in-skyrim)

I have searched on the internet for this, and there appears to be only scripts to remove items from the inventory but not mark as complete in the journal.

This happens usually because I inadvertently completed a quest before Stuff that I've already done. Examples:

1. Find Rjorrn's Drum
2. Find Finn's Lute
3. "Speak to Nelacar" entry in *The Black Star*

These are all for now, but I'm sure more will come as I continue exploring Skyrim.

Does anyone know the script to mark these tasks "finished", because it makes me *twitch*.

And I did try *setstage missionName stagenumber* but that does not affect the journal... help!

Comment: Oh yes, this _is_ a duplicate question. I'm sorry, I did search a lot for something similar as I'm sure others would be facing this, but I never found anything that matches exactly. I hope this is not greatly inappropriate - and the answers for that question completely answer my question :)

Comment: no problem, duplicates serves as guide posts to other questions so its entirely fine.