# Dawnstar Inn quest stays active

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have received the bounty mission from the innkeeper in Dawnstar to kill some giant. I have promptly did so, but after getting the reward from Jarl it still says to pick up my reward from him, but the quest is complete. It happened to me two times now and it bothers me to see it in the quest list.

Is there a console command to list all active quest IDs so I can set it to completed? Any another method to get rid of it will be appreciated too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to clear quests from your journal in skyrim](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/is-there-a-way-to-clear-quests-from-your-journal-in-skyrim)

Comment: I beg to differ. I am not asking about a way to sort or advance the quests using console, nor is the question about having too much active quests. It's just an annoying bug. For me at least, as I want to have my journal nice and tidy.

Comment: This is the same issue, the quest remains in the journal even though you have completed it.  The only way to do it is through the console.  If you are playing on xbox or PS3, then I'm afraid you are out of luck.

Comment: I am playing on the PC. And I know how to set it to the neccesary stage, problem is that it's a radiant quest and I can't find the quest ID anywhere.

Comment: It looks like the quest id is [BQ03](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Bounty:_Giant)

Comment: Nope. It only gives me the reward. And since none of the stages are marked as completing it it's no surprise. I have also tried Favor153, but that does nothing. Isn't there a file for each save that holds the state of the journal?

Comment: nope, if there were a solution would have been posted in the other question

Comment: I actually have *5* of that quest stuck in my journal. Hopefully after the new year, when they've switched from fixing code bugs to fixing script bugs, it will get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my game, there are a few quests; all in the miscellaneous part that do not go away, some are to receive bounty payments, some are to kill beasts or giants etc, and others are random things also.

Why these happen I'm not sure, but just to let you know - it's not just your game, it is happening all around. It could be something to do with quests crossing between others and so something has gone wrong, something is missing or it just doesn't know it's been completed, even though it has. It's hard to explain.

The answer I do not know, so all this was actually a waste of your time, but I do hope its somewhat reassuring...

Comment: Thank you for your reassurance :D I can see that Skyrim follows the best of Bethesdas traditions of being buggy as hell. I have seen dragons flying backwards, broken quests, undroppable objects, random crashes... One would think that since this is the fifth try they had they would finally get it straight. But that wouldn't be Bethesda, would it. And on a final note, the more I am playing the game, the worse it gets. At first it seemed really awesome, but the more I play it the more it seems just like a boosted up Oblivion.