# How do I get rid of quests stuck in my quest log?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to clear quests from your journal in skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/is-there-a-way-to-clear-quests-from-your-journal-in-skyrim)

I have a couple of misc objective that are stuck in my quest log and I can't seem to delete them. I've tried using 'showquesttargets', but only the quests which are actually active show up there.

Comment: I think that question refers more to dropping radiant quests accidentally picked up. Also, not misc. objectives.

Comment: That question says nothing specific like you said. It asks generically how to get rid of any quest that you don't want. The answer is the same for both questions, whether you like the answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is to use **SETSTAGE** for the duplicated quests. I happened to me with the "Visit Azura Shrine" quest.

**SetStage**   - Used to set the quest stage (Useful for bugged quests) use command ShowQuestTargets for quest IDs and player.sqs to show how many stages are there (note that you have set the stage one at a time in order to get its effect.)