# Can I delete quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to clear quests from your journal in skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/is-there-a-way-to-clear-quests-from-your-journal-in-skyrim)

In my Skyrim game, I have too many quests!

Is there a way to remove some (preferably without the console), so I don't feel so overwhelmed?

Comment: By "without the console", do you also want to exclude manual manipulation of the saved game?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming what you are looking for is a way to simply remove the quests from your list but in a manner that you can get them again later? ie: Dropping a quest in WoW cause you dont want to deal with it and just pick it up again at a later point in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered [***HERE***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36036/is-there-a-way-to-clear-quests-from-your-journal-in-skyrim)
To answer with out a link, the only ways to remove quests as of now are by either completing them or possibly by killing the person who gave you the quest. See the link above for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't answer your question but it might change your mind. I take on every quest I get offered because I noticed one location usually supports several different quests. So when I'm there I can complete more that one quest at a time. 
Here's my other suggestions:
Double check your active quests, all you may have to do is complete a simple assignment or talk to someone to finish it. Also, you might check out an online game guide and find out which quests are quick to complete, that should thin them out a little.
I hope that helps.